# AWS CloudWatch Agent: NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am receiving the following errors in the EC2 CloudWatch Agent logs, `/var/logs/awslogs.log`:

[image]

I verified the EC2 has a role:

[image]

And the role has the correct policies:
[image]
[image]

I have set the correct region in /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf:
[image]

I noticed that running `aws configure list` in the EC2 gives this:
[image]

Is this incorrect? Should it list the profile (EC2_Cloudwatch_Profile) there?

Answer (score 0):

I was using terraform and reprovisioning by doing:

`terraform destroy && terraform apply`

Looks like due to IAM being a global service it is "eventually consistent" and not "immediately consistent", when the profile instance was destroyed, the `terraform apply` began too quickly. Despite the "destroy" being complete, the arn for the previous profile instance was still there, and was re-used. However, the ID changed to a new ID.

Replacing the EC2 would bring it up to speed with the correct ID. However, my solution is to just wait longer between terraform destroy and apply.